# Rearrange Array Alternately

Tags: java, arrays

Given a sorted array of positive integers. Your task is to rearrange  the array elements alternatively i.e first element should be max value, second should be min value, third should be second max, fourth should be second min and so on.

```
class RearrangeAlternate{
public void swapMax(int arr[], int i, int n){
    int x = arr[i];
    int j;
    for(j = n-1; j>i; j--){
        if(arr[j] > x){
            break;
        }
    }
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
public void swapMin(int arr[], int i, int n){
    int x = arr[i];
    int j;
    int res = n-1;
    for(j = n-1; j>i; j--){
        if(arr[j] < x){
            if(arr[j] < arr[res]){
                res = j;
            }
        }
    }
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[res];
    arr[res] = temp;
}
public void rearrange(int arr[], int n){
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        if(i%2 == 0){
            swapMax(arr, i, n);
        }
        else swapMin(arr, i, n);
    }
} 
}
```

### Please help me find the error

> It is showing wrong output for somecases.
>   eg.
>   82
>   12 23 28 43 44 59 60 68 70 85 88 92 124 125 136 168 171 173 179 199 212 230 277 282 306 314 316 325 328 336 337 363 365 368 369 371 374 387 394 414 422 427 430 435 457 493 506 527 531 538 541 546 568 583 650 691 730 737 751 764 778 783 785 789 794 803 809 815 847 858 863 874 887 896 916 920 926 927 930 957 981 997
>   
>   My codes output: 997 12 981 23 957 28 930 43 927 44 926 59 920 60 916 68 896 70 887 85 874 88 863 92 858 124 847 125 815 136 809 168 803 171 794 173 789 179 785 199 783 212 778 230 764 277 751 282 737 306 730 314 691 316 650 325 568 328 527 336 506 337 430 363 374 369 541 365 583 368 531 371 493 387 538 394 457 414 435 422 546 427
>   
>   Answer: 997 12 981 23 957 28 930 43 927 44 926 59 920 60 916 68 896 70 887 85 874 88 863 92 858 124 847 125 815 136 809 168 803 171 794 173 789 179 785 199 783 212 778 230 764 277 751 282 737 306 730 314 691 316 650 325 583 328 568 336 546 337 541 363 538 365 531 368 527 369 506 371 493 374 457 387 435 394 430 414 427 422

Comment: try with small examples, re-read the logic, and debug your code. smaller arrays will make it easier to spot the difference

Comment: I assume you are not allowed to create a new array?

Comment: It is working for small arrays. I tried for both even and odd number of tems. @Stultuske

Comment: yes., you are right. And i'm not creating any new array. @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your array is sorted, you can simply do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                // Store the last element to 'temp'
                temp = arr[arr.length - 1];
                // Shift all elements, starting from index, 'i', to one place right
                for (int j = arr.length - 2; j >= i; j--) {
                    arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                }
                // Put the value stored in 'temp' to index, 'i'
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[10, 1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5]
```

Comment: No. Your solution is perfectly correct, but i wanted to know where am i doing it wrong in my code and can you optimize your solution more?

Comment: You need to debug your code and find out the problem with your logic. You have mentioned that your logic works for a small array but I can see that it will fail for an array as small as `{ 12, 23, 28, 43, 44, 59, 60, 68, 70, 85, 88, 92, 124 }`. The key to mastering the programming skill to use simple logic and also to put comments in your code so that it can be understood why you are doing something. The simpler your logic is, the easier it is to find any problem with it. Wish you success!

Answer (score 3):

Since the array is sorted and we need to rearrange alternatively,we can use the technique to store two numbers at a single position in such a manner that we are also able to retrieve back the original element when required.
Let's say we need to store n1 and n2 at same position then we can formulate it like :
======================    n1 = n1 + (n2%z)*z   ======================
To extract n1 we can modulo n1 by z and to extract n2 we can divide n1 by z.
For more detailed explanation,you can refer this video : https://youtu.be/KOglcclYgXI

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentioned below solves the problem in **O(N) Time complexity** and **O(1) Space Complexity** **WITHOUT** using the *"storing 2 values at one location concept"*. Moreover this algorithm can also handle duplicate values & float values given the input list is non-decreasingly sorted and consists of positive real numbers only.

PS: If you wish you can modify my algorithm slightly to make it work for negative values as well.

**Please don't get intimidated by looking at the code. Implementation is very simple. Algorithm might be a bit tricky to understand.**

```py
    def reArrange(arr, print_arr_state=True):
        # arr: non-decreasingly sorted list of positive floats/ints
        length = len(arr)
        for i in range(length):
            if arr[i] > 0:
                cycler(arr, i, length, print_arr_state)
            arr[i] = abs(arr[i]) # This is the tricky part
            # printing the array after every iteration
            if print_arr_state:
                print('after', i, 'th iteration:', arr)


    def cycler(arr, start_index, length, print_cycler_array=True):
        if print_cycler_array:
            print('cycler function:', arr, end=' ---> ')

        half_length_index = length // 2
        swap_index = start_index
        current_value = arr[start_index]
        while True:
            if swap_index < half_length_index:
                swap_index = 2 * swap_index + 1
            else:
                swap_index = 2 * (length - 1 - swap_index)

            # Placing the current value at swap_index and making the making current_value variable refer to the value which was at swap_index
            swap_value = arr[swap_index]
            arr[swap_index] = -1 * current_value # -1 * ?? This is the tricky part of the algo
            current_value = swap_value

            # cycler function will not stop until the simple cycle is complete
            # simple cycle is complete when swap_index == start_index
            if swap_index == start_index:
                if print_cycler_array:
                    print(arr)
                return
```

**Giving Input (input_array) and Calling reArrange function:**

```
input_array = [0.1, 2, 3.2, 3.3, 3.3, 4, 5.7, 5.7, 6.8, 7, 8, 9]
reArrange(input_array)
```

**Output:**

```
answer_array = [9, 0.1, 8, 2, 7, 3.2, 6.8, 3.3, 5.7, 3.3, 5.7, 4]
```

### Understanding the algorithm

#### Tricky part of the algorithm:

Every value belongs to exactly 1 cycle and this cycle is a simple cycle (simple cycle vs complex cycle in graphs). One execution of *cycler* function corresponds to one cycle which is also a simple cycle.

Whenever I cover a value during a cycle, I multiply it with -1 (to indicate that it is covered) and store it in the input array itself.
During the i-th iteration of the loop of *reArrange* function, if I find the i-th value to be negative I get an indication that this value is a part of a cycle executed for some j-th iteration (where j < i), thus I don't call the *cycler* function on this value. But if this value is positive (indicating that none of cycles executed so far has covered this value), it implies that it is not covered yet and hence should be covered in the i-th iteration using the *cycler* function.

But wait!, if I have multiplied all values with -1 my final answer will be **-1 * *correct_answer_array***. To solve this problem, one solution is to reiterate my *answer_array* (which was *input_array* initially and now has transformed to my *answer_array*) and take the absolute of each value **OR** I can do the same thing during my first and only iteration (of *reArrange* function's loop) by taking the absolute of the value before moving to the i+1-th iteration.

### Some valid questions

There are few aspects of this algorithm that I haven't covered in this post. Let me leave you with some of these aspects in the form of questions:

1. Is the while loop of *cycler* function guaranteed to terminate?
2. Why should we not cover a value more than once?
3. How can we handle the negative input values (if any)?
4. Isn't a single cycle sufficient to cover all the values of the input_array. (Isn't a single call of the *cycler* function sufficient to cover all the values)?
   Hint: eg: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7, this example will lead to 3 cycles. (*cycler* function will be called thrice)
5. What happens during a single call of cycler function?
   Hint: Every value which is the part of this cycle shifts to the place where it is supposed to be in the *correct_answer_array*. Once a value is at its correct place, it should not be disturbed again.

Please visit the comments section at the bottom of [this page (GeeksforGeeks)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rearrange-array-maximum-minimum-form) to see the dry run of the algorithm. Please make sure you read all of the comments by me because I have created a bit of mess there.

Answer (score 0):

*using lambda — doing the rearranging outside the original* `arr`
O(n) time complexity

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
int[] tmp = IntStream.range( 0, (arr.length + 1) / 2 )
    .flatMap( n -> IntStream.of( arr[arr.length - n - 1], arr[n] ) ).toArray();
System.arraycopy( tmp, 0, arr, 0, arr.length );
```

gets for `arr`: `[11, 1, 10, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7, 5, 6]`

Answer (score -1):

Given a sorted array of positive integers. Your task is to rearrange the array elements alternatively i.e first element should be max value, second should be min value, third should be second max, fourth should be second min and so on.

```
//c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace vijay
{
    class oddEven
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] arr = new int[n];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            arr[i]=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
           // example input int[] arr = {8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 };
            Array.Sort(arr);           //sorting array
            Array.Sort(arr);
            int f = 1,f1=0;  
            int[] dummy = new int[n];
            int a = arr.Length / 2;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
               if(i<a)                //first half add in even position 
                {
                    dummy[f]=arr[i];
                    f += 2;
                }
                else                 //second half add in odd positions
                {
                    dummy[f1] = arr[i];
                    f1 += 2;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n");      //print the result
            foreach(int q in dummy)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(q);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

```py
//python
list=[2,5,8,9,4,6,7,1]
a=sorted(list)
b=reversed(sorted(list))
c=a[0:len(a)//2]
d=a[len(a)//2:][::-1]
for i in range(len(c)):
    print(d[i],end=' ')
    print(c[i],end=' ')
```

Comment: Are you sure to answer the good question ? It seems to don't have any link with the question, not same language not same code ...

Comment: Code only answers aren't considered good practice. Please explain your code and how it answers the question

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Elikill58 i think... i give a good answer  please recheck again now you will able to understand what i tried..

Comment: @DevWithZachary thank you seeing post . i am rearrange my code please check again tq

Comment: You copy the description from the OP of what he wants... Also it's already in wrong language, So it can't help him.

Comment: yeah your right @Elikill58 but i give a logic ... language that not a metter at all and c# ,java have smililer function